# Get most recent element in Grafana from an Elasticsearch data source

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

In the Grafana Query editor, I'm trying to replicate the following elasticsearch DSL query:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
        "hostname": "A"
    }
  },
    "sort": [
    { "utctimestamp": "desc" }
  ],
  "size": 1
}
```

It gives me most recent document in the index which has a field "hostname" with a value of "A".

I can get the value of the `risk_num` field from the *most recent* element of my elasticsearch index with the following query :

[image]

However, if i add a filter like `hostname: "A"` in the "Query" field, it will work if the most recent document in the index matches the 'A' hostname, but if the most recent document in the index has another hostname (let's say "B"), it will return the datetime of the document with the "B" hostname, and a risk_num value of null.

Example :
I have the two following documents saved in my ES index :

```json
{
    "_source": {
        "hostname": "B",
        "risk_num": 20,
        "utctimestamp": "2020-10-21T12:12:34.356Z"
    }
},
{
    "_source": {
        "hostname": "A",
        "risk_num": 10,
        "utctimestamp": "2020-10-21T12:11:03.489Z"
    }
}
```

The document with hostname B is more recent that the document with hostname A.

Request for hostname B is OK:

[image]

Request for hostname A returns null (expected: 10):

[image]

Any idea how I can get the last document of an index satisfying a certain condition in Grafana ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it working correctly by setting the "Min Doc Count" option to 1:

[image]